# Cors issue with net.core and angular4 app - works on azurewebsites.net domain not on custom

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, cors

I am hosting a dev environment on azurewebsites.net domain.
**Webapp is on webapp.azurewebsites.net

Api is on api.azurewebsites.net**

This scenario works ok, which means app client side and api server side they are properly set up(cors).

The issue appears on my live scenario where i have custom domain and https certificate installed:
**Webapp is on www.webapp.com

Api is on api.webapp.com**

I checked three times that build properly replaces values for cors origin set up(web.config), and all values are correct, but I still get an error on live custom domain.

Error:

> Failed to load https://api.webapp.com/api/connect/token: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.webapp.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I have no issues accessing api via postman of course.

Api startup.cs:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins(Configuration.GetSection("HostSettings:WebAppClientUrl").Value.ToString())
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });

            ConfigureDependencyInjection(services);

            // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
            services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
            {
                x.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });

                // UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds replacement for .NET Core
                x.CustomSchemaIds(y => y.FullName);

                //Set the comments path for the swagger json and ui.
                var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "Api.xml");
                x.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });

            // Add framework services.
            services
                .AddMvc()
                .AddFluentValidation(x => x.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CreateViewModelValidator>());

            services.AddMvcCore()
                .AddJsonFormatters(x => x.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()));

            // Add di framework
            var container = new Container(new DependencyInjectionRegistry());
            container.Populate(services);

            services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(container.GetInstance));
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
        }
```

Also in configure method:

```
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

appsesttings.json:
{

```
  "HostSettings": {
    "WebAppClientUrl": "https://www.webapp.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us any CORS related lines in the web.config and in your code behind.

Comment: You need to configure it on Startup class on Configure/ConfigureServices method. Not sure what you mean with web.config. Post your startup class here so we can see it.

Comment: I have added startup.cs code

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to Azure and set up CORS on web api there.